# Opera Tab Malfunction

Tags: opera

I am 99.9% certain that a single TAB in Opera 11.50 (XP 32-bit in VirtualBox on an XP Pro 64-bit) has ceased to run Javascript.  This just wasted about an hour of my time looking for an error in css/Javascript/HTML that wasn't there, since sometimes little things that run on the other browsers will break Opera rendering.  ( I had been simply refreshing screens in the seven different browsers while testing some development. )  The tab runs no Javascript on other sites that function normally on all browsers, and other tabs in the SAME Opera window

My question is, has anyone else come across this before that a single tab would completely lose functionality?!?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use alert(), confirm() or similar? Perhaps you've accidentally ticked the "stop running scripts" box that appears if a site uses multiple alert boxes? This can disable JavaScript for a single tab.